# Infrequent measurements in Gekko with extra simulation points

Tags: python, ode, differential-equations, gekko

I'm solving a more complex dynamic data reconciliation problem that is similar to the example problem posted in the [APMonitor dynamic optimization course](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/DynamicEstimation). Similar to this problem, I have infrequent measurements at irregular intervals. Instead of using the more accurate `NODES=5` (for increased accuracy), I would like to have more frequent simulation points with `NODES=2` at `[0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6.0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0]` that also includes the infrequent measurements for the objective at `[0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.8, 1]`.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
t_data = [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.8, 1]
x_data = [2.0,  1.6,  1.2, 0.7,  0.3,  0.15]
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = t_data
x = m.Var(value=x_data)     # fit to measurement
xd = m.Param(x_data)
k = m.FV(); k.STATUS = 1    # adjustable parameter
m.Equation(x.dt()== -k * x) # differential equation
m.Minimize((x-xd)**2)
m.options.IMODE = 5   # dynamic estimation
m.options.NODES = 2   # collocation nodes
m.solve(disp=False)   # display solver output
k = k.value[0]
```

One of the reasons for this is that the simulation model needs to solve more frequently than the measurements to maintain integration accuracy with `NODES=2`. The exact solution deviates from the numerical solution if I only solve at the measurement points.

[image: Exact solution]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # plot solution
plt.plot(m.time,x.value,'bo',\
         label='Predicted (k='+str(np.round(k,2))+')')
plt.plot(m.time,x_data,'rx',label='Measured')
# plot exact solution
t = np.linspace(0,1); xe = 2*np.exp(-k*t)
plt.plot(t,xe,'k:',label='Exact Solution')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Time'), plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.show()
```

How can I use a lower order collocation mode with more frequent simulation points and infrequent measurements in Gekko?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine infrequent measurements with more frequent simulation steps in Pandas with the `join()` function:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# measurements
t_data = [0,0.1,0.2,0.4,0.8,1]
x_data = [2.0,1.6,1.2,0.7,0.3,0.15]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'time':t_data,'x':x_data})
df1.set_index('time', inplace=True)
# simulation time points
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'time':np.linspace(0,1,51)})
df2.set_index('time', inplace=True)
# merge dataframes
df = df2.join(df1,how='outer')
# get True (1) or False (0) for measurement
df['meas'] = (df['x'].values==df['x'].values).astype(int)
# replace NaN with zeros
df0 = df.fillna(value=0)
print(df.head(15))
```

This gives the combined set with `NaN` for the missing data points.

```
        x  meas
time           
0.00  2.0     1
0.02  NaN     0
0.04  NaN     0
0.06  NaN     0
0.08  NaN     0
0.10  1.6     1
0.12  NaN     0
0.14  NaN     0
0.16  NaN     0
0.18  NaN     0
0.20  1.2     1
0.22  NaN     0
0.24  NaN     0
0.26  NaN     0
0.28  NaN     0
```

You can then create a modified objective function that uses `meas` to control when to minimize the simulation and measurement only at the defined points.

```py
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = df.index.values
x = m.Var(value=x_data[0])     # fit to measurement
xd = m.Param(df0['x'].values)
meas = m.Param(df0['meas'].values)
k = m.FV(); k.STATUS = 1    # adjustable parameter
m.Equation(x.dt()== -k * x) # differential equation
m.Minimize(meas*(x-xd)**2)
m.options.SOLVER = 1  # APOPT solver
m.options.IMODE = 5   # dynamic estimation
m.options.NODES = 2   # collocation nodes
m.solve(disp=True)   # display solver output
k = k.value[0]
```

A plot shows the results. I included more data points because `NODES=2` isn't very accurate. A switch to `NODES=3` helps to improve the accuracy much more than adding more points.

[image: Infrequent measurments]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # plot solution
plt.plot(m.time,x.value,'bo',\
         label='Predicted (k='+str(np.round(k,2))+')')
plt.plot(m.time,df['x'].values,'rs',label='Measured')
# plot exact solution
t = np.linspace(0,1); xe = 2*np.exp(-k*t)
plt.plot(t,xe,'k:',label='Exact Solution')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Time'), plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.ylim([-0.2,2.2])
plt.show()
```