# Parameters estimation and least squares minimization - Python and Gekko

Tags: python, gekko

I am trying to estimate 4 parameters (kdoc1, kdoc2, S1, S2), using GEKKO to solve a system of algebraic ordinary equations, minimizing the sum of the squares of the residual error between the observed and predicted values. I am not getting a good adjustment between the measured and the predicted data, do you have any suggestion about what am I doing wrong in the code?
Moreover, I am also trying to add another data set of measurement data. I want the model to do the estimation of the parameters using two measured data sets, I need to minimize the sum of residuals using the two data sets. Have you got any idea on how to do it in the code?

I already add additional points to help the solver converge using the suggestion [python - Infrequent measurements in Gekko with extra simulation points - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65398449/infrequent-measurements-in-gekko-with-extra-simulation-points)

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import math as math
import pandas as pd

#TOC=5.93 mg/L
#M2 C1 5mg/L
#time: [0,0.08333,0.5,1,4,22.61667]; C2 measured: [0,9.33e-5,8.55e-5,8.55e-5,7.77e-5,7.00e-5]
#M4 C1 20mg/l
#time: [0,0.08333,0.5,1,4,22.61667]; C2 measured: [0,2.92e-4,2.72e-4,2.92e-4,2.72e-4,2.14e-4]


#measurements
t_data = [0.08333,0.5,1,4,22.61667]
x_data = [9.33e-5,8.55e-5,8.55e-5,7.77e-5,7.00e-5]
#x_data2 = [2.92e-4,2.72e-4,2.92e-4,2.72e-4,2.14e-4]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'time':t_data,'x':x_data})
df1.set_index('time', inplace=True)
# simulation time points
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'time':np.linspace(0,25,51)}) #(0,25,51)
df2.set_index('time', inplace=True)
# merge dataframes
df = df2.join(df1,how='outer')
# get True (1) or False (0) for measurement
df['meas'] = (df['x'].values==df['x'].values).astype(int)
# replace NaN with zeros
df0 = df.fillna(value=0)

#Estimator Model
m = GEKKO()
m.time = df.index.values

# adjustable parameters
kdoc1 = m.FV() #m-1h-1
kdoc2 = m.FV() #m-1h-1
S1 = m.FV()
S2 = m.FV()

#State variables
# M (mol/L)
C0 = m.Var(value=8.00e-5)
C1 = m.Var(value=1.36e-3)
C2 = m.Var(value=x_data[0])
C2m = m.Param(df0['x'].values) 
meas = m.Param(df0['meas'].values)
m.Minimize(meas*(C2-C2m)**2)
C3 = m.Var(value=0)
C4 = m.Var(value=3.16e-8)
C5 = m.Var(value=3.83e-7)
C6 = m.Var(value=0)
C7 = m.Var(value=0)
C8 = m.Var(value=0)
C9 = m.Var(value=0)
C10 = m.Var(value=0)
C11 = m.Var(value=0)
C12 = m.Var(value=3.21e-3)
TOC = m.Var(value=5.93)#mg-C/L 
cC1 = m.Var(value=0)
cC2 = m.Var(value=0)

#temperature ºC
T = 20 

#Rate constants
k1 = 2040000000*math.exp(-1887/(273.15+T))*3600
k2 = 138000000*math.exp(-8800/(273.15+T))*3600
k3 = 300000*math.exp(-2010/(273.15+T))*3600
k4 = 0.00000065*3600
k6 = 26700*3600
k7 = 167*3600
k8 = 27700*3600
k9 = 8300*3600
k10 = 0
k5 = 37800000000*math.exp(-2169/(273.15+T))*C4+2.52e25*math.exp(-16860/(273.15+T))*C10+0.87*math.exp(-503/(273.15+T))*C9
 

r1 = k1 * C0 * C1
r2 = k2 * C2
r3 = k3 * C0 * C2
r4 = k4 * C3
r5 = k5 * C2 * C2
r6 = k6 * C3 * C1* C4
r7 = k7 * C3 * C5
r8 = k8 * C6 * C3
r9 = k9 * C6 * C2
r10 = k10 * C2 * C3
r11 = kdoc1*S1*TOC*C2/12000
r12 = kdoc2*S2*TOC*C0/12000

t = m.Param(value=m.time)
m.Equation(C0.dt()== -r1 + r2 - r3 + r4 + r8 - r12)
m.Equation(C1.dt()== -r1 + r2 + r5 - r6 + r11)
m.Equation(C2.dt()== r1 - r2 - r3 + r4 - r5 + r6 - r9 - r10 - r11)
m.Equation(C3.dt()== r3 - r4 + r5 - r6 - r7 - r8 - r10)
m.Equation(C4.dt()== 0)
m.Equation(C5 == 1e-14/C4)
m.Equation(C6.dt()== r7 - r8 - r9)
m.Equation(C7 == (3.16e-8*C0)/C4)
m.Equation(C1 == (5.01e-10*C8)/C4)
m.Equation(C11 == (5.01e-11*C10)/C4)
m.Equation(C9 == (5.01e-7*C9)/C4)
m.Equation(C10 == C12 - 2*C11 - C5 + C4)
m.Equation(C12.dt()== 0)
m.Equation(TOC.dt()== 0)
m.Equation(cC1 == 17000*C1)
m.Equation(cC2 == 51500*C2)

#Application options
m.options.SOLVER = 1 #APOPT solver
m.options.IMODE = 5 #Dynamic Simultaneous - estimation
m.options.EV_TYPE = 2 #absolute error
m.options.NODES = 5 #collocation nodes (2,5)

if True:
    kdoc1.STATUS=1
    kdoc2.STATUS=1
    S1.STATUS=1
    S2.STATUS=1

#Solve
m.solve(disp=False)


#Results
data={'Time (h)':t,'C0 (M)':C0.value,'C1 (M)':C1.value, 'C2 (M)':C2.value,'C3 (M)':C3.value,'C4 (M)':C4.value,'C5 (M)':C5.value,'C6 (M)':C6.value,'C7 (M)':C7.value,'C8 (M)':C8.value,'C9 (M)':C9.value,'C10 (M)':C10.value,'C11 (M)':C11.value,'c12 (M)':C12.value}
dfr = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Time (h)','C0 (M)','C1 (M)','C2 (M)','C3 (M)','C4 (M)','C5 (M)','C6 (M)','C7 (M)','C8 (M)','C9 (M)','C10 (M)','C11 (M)','C12 (M)'])
#dfr.to_csv(r'C:\dfestimation.csv', index = False)

print('Solution')
print('kdoc1 = ' + str(kdoc1.value[0]))
print('kdoc2 = ' + str(kdoc2.value[0]))
print('S1 = ' + str(S1.value[0]))
print('S2 = ' + str(S2.value[0]))

plt.figure(1,figsize=(12,8))
plt.subplot(3,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,C2.value,'bo',label='Predicted')
plt.plot(m.time,df['x'].values,'rs',label='Meas')
plt.plot(m.time,C2.value,label ='C2')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.subplot(3,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time,cC2.value,label ='C2')
plt.plot(m.time,cC1.value,label ='C1')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.subplot(3,1,3)
plt.plot(m.time,C0.value,label ='C0')
plt.plot(m.time,C1.value,label ='C1')
plt.plot(m.time,C3.value,label ='C3')
plt.plot(m.time,C4.value,label ='C4')
plt.plot(m.time,C5.value,label ='C5')
plt.plot(m.time,C6.value,label ='C6')
plt.plot(m.time,C7.value,label ='C7-')
plt.plot(m.time,C8.value,label ='C8')
plt.plot(m.time,C9.value,label ='C9')
plt.plot(m.time,C10.value,label ='C10')
plt.plot(m.time,C11.value,label ='C11')
plt.plot(m.time,C12.value,label ='C12')

plt.xlabel('time (h)')
plt.ylabel('Concentration (mol/L)')
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are new results that are closer.

[image: Regression results]

I added constraints to the parameters and gave them non-zero starting values (1).

```py
kdoc1 = m.FV(1,lb=0.01,ub=10) #m-1h-1
kdoc2 = m.FV(1,lb=0.01,ub=10) #m-1h-1
S1 = m.FV(1,lb=0.01,ub=10)
S2 = m.FV(1,lb=0.01,ub=10)
```

Calculated the initial conditions for `C0` and `C1` because these were creating a large instantaneous jump in `C2`. If these initial concentrations are known then you may need to switch back to a fixed initial condition.

```py
m.free_initial(C0)
m.free_initial(C1)
```

Scaled the objective function because 1e-4**2 is already a small number and may already meet the objective convergence criteria. The objective function value of the original problem was very small. I made each square value approximately equal to 1 as a starting point.

```py
m.Minimize(meas*(1e4*(C2-C2m))**2)
```

This provides a reasonable solution that you can start with to get the regression results that you need.

```
kdoc1 = 3.7210285146
kdoc2 = 2.5743961631
S1 = 3.7210285146
S2 = 2.5743961631
```

The parameter values do not finish at a constraint so it implies that this solution is optimal. Even though the parameter constraints are not active at the end, the constraints do help to guide the solver on the appropriate search area.

[image: Concentration profiles]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import math as math
import pandas as pd

#measurements
t_data = [0.08333,0.5,1,4,22.61667]
x_data = [9.33e-5,8.55e-5,8.55e-5,7.77e-5,7.00e-5]
#x_data2 = [2.92e-4,2.72e-4,2.92e-4,2.72e-4,2.14e-4]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'time':t_data,'x':x_data})
df1.set_index('time', inplace=True)
# simulation time points
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'time':np.linspace(0,25,51)})
df2.set_index('time', inplace=True)
# merge dataframes
df = df2.join(df1,how='outer')
# get True (1) or False (0) for measurement
df['meas'] = (df['x'].values==df['x'].values).astype(int)
# replace NaN with zeros
df0 = df.fillna(value=0)
#Estimator Model
m = GEKKO()
m.time = df.index.values

# adjustable parameters
kdoc1 = m.FV(1,lb=0.01,ub=10) #m-1h-1
kdoc2 = m.FV(1,lb=0.01,ub=10) #m-1h-1
S1 = m.FV(1,lb=0.01,ub=10)
S2 = m.FV(1,lb=0.01,ub=10)

#State variables
# M (mol/L)
C0 = m.Var(value=8.00e-5,lb=0,ub=1e-3)
m.free_initial(C0)
C1 = m.Var(value=1.36e-3,lb=0,ub=2e-3)
m.free_initial(C1)
C2 = m.Var(value=x_data[0])
C2m = m.Param(df0['x'].values,lb=0)
meas = m.Param(df0['meas'].values)
m.Minimize(meas*(1e4*(C2-C2m))**2)
C3 = m.Var(value=0)
C4 = m.Var(value=3.16e-8)
C5 = m.Var(value=3.83e-7)
C6 = m.Var(value=0)
C7 = m.Var(value=0)
C8 = m.Var(value=0)
C9 = m.Var(value=0)
C10 = m.Var(value=0)
C11 = m.Var(value=0)
C12 = m.Var(value=3.21e-3)
TOC = m.Var(value=5.93)#mg-C/L 
cC1 = m.Var(value=0)
cC2 = m.Var(value=0)

#temperature ºC
T = 20 

#Rate constants
k1 = 2040000000*math.exp(-1887/(273.15+T))*3600
k2 = 138000000*math.exp(-8800/(273.15+T))*3600
k3 = 300000*math.exp(-2010/(273.15+T))*3600
k4 = 0.00000065*3600
k6 = 26700*3600
k7 = 167*3600
k8 = 27700*3600
k9 = 8300*3600
k10 = 0
k5 = 37800000000*math.exp(-2169/(273.15+T))*C4\
     +2.52e25*math.exp(-16860/(273.15+T))*C10\
     +0.87*math.exp(-503/(273.15+T))*C9
 
r1 = k1 * C0 * C1
r2 = k2 * C2
r3 = k3 * C0 * C2
r4 = k4 * C3
r5 = k5 * C2 * C2
r6 = k6 * C3 * C1* C4
r7 = k7 * C3 * C5
r8 = k8 * C6 * C3
r9 = k9 * C6 * C2
r10 = k10 * C2 * C3
r11 = kdoc1*S1*TOC*C2/12000
r12 = kdoc2*S2*TOC*C0/12000

t = m.Param(value=m.time)
m.Equation(C0.dt()== -r1 + r2 - r3 + r4 + r8 - r12)
m.Equation(C1.dt()== -r1 + r2 + r5 - r6 + r11)
m.Equation(C2.dt()== r1 - r2 - r3 + r4 - r5 + r6 - r9 - r10 - r11)
m.Equation(C3.dt()== r3 - r4 + r5 - r6 - r7 - r8 - r10)
m.Equation(C4.dt()== 0)
m.Equation(C5 == 1e-14/C4)
m.Equation(C6.dt()== r7 - r8 - r9)
m.Equation(C7 == (3.16e-8*C0)/C4)
m.Equation(C1 == (5.01e-10*C8)/C4)
m.Equation(C11 == (5.01e-11*C10)/C4)
m.Equation(C9 == (5.01e-7*C9)/C4)
m.Equation(C10 == C12 - 2*C11 - C5 + C4)
m.Equation(C12.dt()== 0)
m.Equation(TOC.dt()== 0)
m.Equation(cC1 == 17000*C1)
m.Equation(cC2 == 51500*C2)

#Application options
m.options.SOLVER = 3 #APOPT solver
m.options.IMODE = 5 #Dynamic Simultaneous - estimation
m.options.EV_TYPE = 2 #absolute error
m.options.NODES = 3 #collocation nodes (2,5)

if True:
    kdoc1.STATUS=1
    kdoc2.STATUS=1
    S1.STATUS=1
    S2.STATUS=1

#Solve
m.solve(disp=True)

print('Solution')
print('kdoc1 = ' + str(kdoc1.value[0]))
print('kdoc2 = ' + str(kdoc2.value[0]))
print('S1 = ' + str(S1.value[0]))
print('S2 = ' + str(S2.value[0]))

plt.figure(1,figsize=(8,5))
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,C2.value,'bo',label='Predicted')
plt.plot(m.time,df['x'].values,'rs',label='Meas')
plt.plot(m.time,C2.value,label ='C2')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time,cC2.value,label ='C2')
plt.plot(m.time,cC1.value,label ='C1')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel('time (h)')

plt.figure(2,figsize=(12,8))
plt.subplot(4,3,1)
plt.plot(m.time,C0.value,label ='C0')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(4,3,2)
plt.plot(m.time,C1.value,label ='C1')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(4,3,3)
plt.plot(m.time,C3.value,label ='C3')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(4,3,4)
plt.plot(m.time,C4.value,label ='C4')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(4,3,5)
plt.plot(m.time,C5.value,label ='C5')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(4,3,6)
plt.plot(m.time,C6.value,label ='C6')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(4,3,7)
plt.plot(m.time,C7.value,label ='C7-')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(4,3,8)
plt.plot(m.time,C8.value,label ='C8')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(4,3,9)
plt.plot(m.time,C9.value,label ='C9')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('time (h)')

plt.subplot(4,3,10)
plt.plot(m.time,C10.value,label ='C10')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('time (h)')

plt.subplot(4,3,11)
plt.plot(m.time,C11.value,label ='C11')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('time (h)')

plt.subplot(4,3,12)
plt.plot(m.time,C12.value,label ='C12')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('time (h)')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

@John Hedengren, thank you for your support. I modified my code following your ideas and added another set of data following your explanations here:

[How to set up GEKKO for parameter estimation from multiple independent sets of data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65695486/how-to-set-up-gekko-for-parameter-estimation-from-multiple-independent-sets-of-d)

 However, I am not reaching a good solution, particularly for measurement 4. Have you got any ideas about how can I adjust it better? Thank you for your time and help.

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import math as math
import pandas as pd

#data set 1
t_data1 = [0.08333,0.5,1,4,22.61667]
x_data1 = [7.77e-5,7e-5,7e-5,6.22e-5,3.89e-5]
x_data1mgl = [4,3.6,3.6,3.2,2]

#data set 2
t_data4 = [0.08333,0.5,1,4,22.61667]
x_data4 = [2.92e-4,2.72e-4,2.92e-4,2.72e-4,2.14e-4]
x_data4mgl = [15,14,15,14,11]

#combine data and time in the same dataframe
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'time':t_data1,'x1':x_data1})
data4 = pd.DataFrame({'time':t_data4,'x4':x_data4})
data1.set_index('time', inplace=True)
data4.set_index('time', inplace=True)


# merge dataframes
data = data1.join(data4, how='outer')

# simulation time points
dftp = pd.DataFrame({'time':np.linspace(0,25,51)})
dftp.set_index('time', inplace=True)

# merge dataframes
df = data.join(dftp,how='outer')

# get True (1) or False (0) for measurement
#df['meas'] = (df['x'].values==df['x'].values).astype(int)
z1 = (df['x1']==df['x1']).astype(int)
z4 = (df['x4']==df['x4']).astype(int)


# replace NaN with zeros
df0 = df.fillna(value=0)

#Estimator Model
m = GEKKO(remote=True)
#m = GEKKO(remote=False) # remote=False to produce local folder with results

m.time = df.index.values

# measurements - Gekko arrays to store measured data
xm = m.Array(m.Param,2)
xm[0].value = df0['x1'].values
xm[1].value = df0['x4'].values


cl=m.Array(m.Var,2)
cl[0].value= 4e-5
cl[1].value= 1.33e-4


TOC=m.Array(m.Var,2)
TOC[0].value= 11.85
TOC[1].value= 11.85


C0=m.Array(m.Var,2)
C1=m.Array(m.Var,2)
cC1=m.Array(m.Var,2)
C2=m.Array(m.Var,2)
C2m=m.Array(m.Var,2)
cC2=m.Array(m.Var,2)
C3=m.Array(m.Var,2)
C4=m.Array(m.Var,2)
C5=m.Array(m.Var,2)
C6=m.Array(m.Var,2)
C7=m.Array(m.Var,2)
C8=m.Array(m.Var,2)
C9=m.Array(m.Var,2)
C10=m.Array(m.Var,2)
C11=m.Array(m.Var,2)
C12=m.Array(m.Var,2)

r1=m.Array(m.Var,2)
r2=m.Array(m.Var,2)
r3=m.Array(m.Var,2)
r4=m.Array(m.Var,2)
r5=m.Array(m.Var,2)
r6=m.Array(m.Var,2)
r7=m.Array(m.Var,2)
r8=m.Array(m.Var,2)
r9=m.Array(m.Var,2)
r10=m.Array(m.Var,2)
r11=m.Array(m.Var,2)
r12=m.Array(m.Var,2)

k5=m.Array(m.Var,2)

#Define GEKKO variables that determine if time point contains data to be used in regression
#index for objective (0=not measured, 1=measured)
zm = m.Array(m.Param,2)
zm[0].value=z1
zm[1].value=z4


# fit to measurement
x=m.Array(m.Var,2)                         
x[0].value=x_data1[0]
x[1].value=x_data4[0]


#adjustable parameters
kdoc1 = 0 #m-1h-1
kdoc2 = m.FV(1,lb=0.01,ub=10) #m-1h-1
S1 = 0
S2 = m.FV(1,lb=0.01,ub=10)

#Define Variables
for i in range(2):

#State variables
# M (mol/L)
    #C0 = m.Var(cl[i])
    C0[i] = m.Var(value=cl[i],lb=0,ub=1e-3)
    C1[i] = m.Var(value=6.9e-6,lb=0,ub=2e-3)
    C2[i] = m.Var(value=x[i],lb=0, ub=1e-3)
    C2m[i] = m.Param(xm[i],lb=0)
    meas = m.Param(zm[i])
    m.Minimize(meas*((C2[i]-C2m[i]))**2)
    C3[i] = m.Var(value=0)
    C4[i] = m.Var(value=3.16e-8)
    C5[i] = m.Var(value=3.83e-7)
    C6[i] = m.Var(value=0)
    C7[i]= m.Var(value=0)
    C8[i] = m.Var(value=0)
    C9[i] = m.Var(value=0)
    C10[i] = m.Var(value=0)
    C11[i] = m.Var(value=0)
    C12[i] = m.Var(value=3.21e-3)
    TOC[i] = m.Var(value=5.93)#mg-C/L 
    cC1[i] = m.Var(value=0)
    cC2[i] = m.Var(value=0)

#temperature ºC
    T = 20 

#Rate constants
    k1 = 2040000000*math.exp(-1887/(273.15+T))*3600
    k2 = 138000000*math.exp(-8800/(273.15+T))*3600
    k3 = 300000*math.exp(-2010/(273.15+T))*3600
    k4 = 0.00000065*3600
    k6 = 26700*3600
    k7 = 167*3600
    k8 = 27700*3600
    k9 = 8300*3600
    k10 = 0
    k5[i] = 37800000000*math.exp(-2169/(273.15+T))*C4[i]\
         +2.52e25*math.exp(-16860/(273.15+T))*C10[i]\
         +0.87*math.exp(-503/(273.15+T))*C9[i]
 
    r1[i] = k1 * C0[i] * C1[i]
    r2[i] = k2 * C2[i]
    r3[i] = k3 * C0[i] * C2[i]
    r4[i] = k4 * C3[i]
    r5[i] = k5[i] * C2[i] * C2[i]
    r6[i] = k6 * C3[i] * C1[i]* C4[i]
    r7[i] = k7 * C3[i] * C5[i]
    r8[i] = k8 * C6[i] * C3[i]
    r9[i] = k9 * C6[i] * C2[i]
    r10[i] = k10 * C2[i] * C3[i]
    r11[i] = kdoc1*S1*TOC[i]*C2[i]/12000
    r12[i] = kdoc2*S2*TOC[i]*C0[i]/12000

    t = m.Param(value=m.time)
    m.Equation(C0[i].dt()== -r1[i] + r2[i] - r3[i] + r4[i] + r8[i] - r12[i])
    m.Equation(C1[i].dt()== -r1[i] + r2[i] + r5[i] - r6[i] + r11[i])
    m.Equation(C2[i].dt()== r1[i] - r2[i] - r3[i] + r4[i] - r5[i] + r6[i] - r9[i] - r10[i] - r11[i])
    m.Equation(C3[i].dt()== r3[i] - r4[i] + r5[i] - r6[i] - r7[i] - r8[i] - r10[i])
    m.Equation(C4[i].dt()== 0)
    m.Equation(C5[i] == 1e-14/C4[i])
    m.Equation(C6[i].dt()== r7[i] - r8[i] - r9[i])
    m.Equation(C7[i] == (3.16e-8*C0[i])/C4[i])
    m.Equation(C1[i] == (5.01e-10*C8[i])/C4[i])
    m.Equation(C11[i] == (5.01e-11*C10[i])/C4[i])
    m.Equation(C9[i] == (5.01e-7*C9[i])/C4[i])
    m.Equation(C10[i] == C12[i] - 2*C11[i] - C5[i] + C4[i])
    m.Equation(C12[i].dt()== 0)
    m.Equation(TOC[i].dt()== 0)
    m.Equation(cC1[i] == 17000*C1[i])
    m.Equation(cC2[i] == 51500*C2[i])
    m.Equation(S1+S2<1)

#Application options
m.options.SOLVER = 3 #IPOPT solver
m.options.IMODE = 5 #Dynamic Simultaneous - estimation = MHE
m.options.EV_TYPE = 2 #absolute error
m.options.NODES = 3 #collocation nodes (2,5)

if True:
    #kdoc1.STATUS=1
    kdoc2.STATUS=1
    #S1.STATUS=1
    S2.STATUS=1

#Solve
#m.open_folder() # open folder if remote=False to see infeasibilities.txt
m.solve(disp=True)


print('Final SSE Objective: ' + str(m.options.objfcnval))

print('Solution')
#print('kdoc1 = ' + str(kdoc1.value[0]))
print('kdoc2 = ' + str(kdoc2.value[0]))
#print('S1 = ' + str(S1.value[0]))
print('S2 = ' + str(S2.value[0]))

plt.figure(1,figsize=(8,5))
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,C2[0],'b.--',label='Predicted 1')
plt.plot(m.time,C2[1],'r.--',label='Predicted 4')


plt.plot(t_data1,x_data1,'bx',label='Meas 1')
plt.plot(t_data4,x_data4,'rx',label='Meas 4')
plt.legend(loc='best')

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time,cC2[0].value,'b',label ='C2_M1')
plt.plot(m.time,cC2[1].value,'r',label ='C2_M4')
plt.plot(t_data1,x_data1mgl,'bx',label='Meas 1')
plt.plot(t_data4,x_data4mgl,'rx',label='Meas 4')


#plt.plot(m.time,cC1.value,label ='C1')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel('time (h)')

plt.figure(2,figsize=(12,8))
plt.subplot(4,3,1)
plt.plot(m.time,C0[i].value,label ='C0')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(4,3,2)
plt.plot(m.time,C1[i].value,label ='C1')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(4,3,3)
plt.plot(m.time,C3[i].value,label ='C3')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(4,3,4)
plt.plot(m.time,C4[i].value,label ='C4')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(4,3,5)
plt.plot(m.time,C5[i].value,label ='C5')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(4,3,6)
plt.plot(m.time,C6[i].value,label ='C6')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(4,3,7)
plt.plot(m.time,C7[i].value,label ='C7')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(4,3,8)
plt.plot(m.time,C8[i].value,label ='C8')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(4,3,9)
plt.plot(m.time,C9[i].value,label ='C9')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('time (h)')

plt.subplot(4,3,10)
plt.plot(m.time,C10[i].value,label ='C10')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('time (h)')

plt.subplot(4,3,11)
plt.plot(m.time,C11[i].value,label ='C11')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('time (h)')

plt.subplot(4,3,12)
plt.plot(m.time,C12[i].value,label ='C12')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('time (h)')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you either add this as an edit to your original question or make a new question that references this one? You posted the question as an answer.

Comment: I did a new question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65852474/parameters-estimation-with-multiple-data-sets-using-gekko